# Use component/tag contents in Marko template

Tags: marko

Say I'd like to have a component that wraps its contents (aka children):

```
<article>
  <header>${input.heading}</header>
  <section> ... contents come here ... </section>
<article>
```

Then use it like:

```
...
<my-article heading='Test'>
  Lorem ipsum <s>dolor</s> sit amet
</my-article>
```

How do I access the contents in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a simple solution:

```marko
<article>
  <header>${input.heading}</header>
  <section><include(input) /></section>
<article>
```

And use:

```marko
   <my-article heading='Test'>
      Lorem ipsum <s>dolor</s> sit amet
   </my-article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - `<include>` reusable/nested content:

```
<article>
  <header>${input.heading}</header>
  <section><include(input.body) /></section>
</article>
```

Then use it like:

```
<my-article heading='Hello'>
  <@body>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <u>amet</u></@body>
</my-article>
```

Comment: Or  use a `<include(input) />` tag